# R Function for Writing Dataframe to SPSS Portable File

Tags: r, file, format, spss

For my current project I still need to export all of the datasets I work on as .sav and .por SPSS files, currently I use SPSS to do this but am trying to shift all of my work to R and don't want to have to switch between the programs just to export the file to .por. I've seen plenty of R packages that allow you to read .por files but haven't found anything that will allow me to export to .por. Is there a function for this? Or a way I could write my own code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For writing to `.sav` I would recommend `haven::write_sav()`.

For writing to `.por` it seems to be a less supported functionality,
but for example [this package on GitHub: readspss](https://rdrr.io/github/JanMarvin/readspss/man/write.por.html) contains a `write.por()` function.